# Chainlink multi-variable responses - results not getting appended

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm trying to implement a [multi-variable job](https://docs.chain.link/docs/example-job-spec-multi-word/) on my local node, however I'm finding that only 1 of the 3 results are being added to the ***chainlink_result_collection*** array in the resultcollect task. My definition is very similar to the example one linked, the main difference being the use of an external adapter

Running the above example [smart contract](https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/) and spec on my node works, and gives [the following output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15g7NZDGbuZxMUUHFd3JXgve3HB5fpDtV/view?usp=sharing). Take note of the ****chainlink_result_collection**** array being appended to after each run. Have linked the output file to stay under the 30k size limit for SO posts

However when I try to run my multi-variable job, I get the following output. Take note of the ****chainlink_result_collection**** after each **resultcollect** task. You can see each time it's being set to the latest return value, instead of being appended to like the previous job output. So the length of the ****chainlink_result_collection**** array at the end is 1 instead of 3 elements

```
{
"id": "c27b2627-3aeb-4acb-8b84-1e191854b25d",
"jobId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
"result": {
  "data": {
    "result": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000002060",
    "address": "0xb6EFEcE462EA6118A0A7EC1F2a3c7033b1F82967",
    "dataPrefix": "0xc23231a259fa1d606b3b1f8d31d6b169af467af60dbf0ac4e0014eb49553ccc70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f08086217d2ab6f717fd7a12cd3c53a94efa6761b2cdfe81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061288b88",
    "unixDateTime": "1625097600",
    "functionSelector": "0x4ab0d190",
    "aggregatorAddress": "0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331",
    "__chainlink_result_collection__": [
      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000002060"
    ]
  },
  "error": "insertEthTx failed while constructing EthTx data: number of collectors 2 != number of types in ABI encoding 4"
},
"status": "errored",
"taskRuns": [
  {
    "id": "5b7a842a-c5bb-47bb-86d6-9ffc9a8d6288",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "address": "0xb6EFEcE462EA6118A0A7EC1F2a3c7033b1F82967",
        "dataPrefix": "0xc23231a259fa1d606b3b1f8d31d6b169af467af60dbf0ac4e0014eb49553ccc70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f08086217d2ab6f717fd7a12cd3c53a94efa6761b2cdfe81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061288b88",
        "roundAnswer": "36893488147419111519",
        "unixDateTime": "1625097600",
        "functionSelector": "0x4ab0d190",
        "laterRoundAnswer": "36893488147419111520",
        "aggregatorAddress": "0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331",
        "earlierRoundAnswer": "36893488147419111518"
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 83,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "historical-price",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.169781+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.169781+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 3
  },
  {
    "id": "ce1394bd-5d9e-4150-8fd2-7d251b69a81d",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "result": "36893488147419111519"
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 84,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "copy",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
        "copyPath": [
          "roundAnswer"
        ]
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.170343+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.170343+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "da32538d-b640-4bcb-8acb-fe9aafa344b0",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "result": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000205f"
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 85,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "ethuint256",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.170885+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.170885+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "372cdf12-8752-492c-9c2d-ff3354d878af",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "result": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000205f",
        "address": "0xb6EFEcE462EA6118A0A7EC1F2a3c7033b1F82967",
        "dataPrefix": "0xc23231a259fa1d606b3b1f8d31d6b169af467af60dbf0ac4e0014eb49553ccc70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f08086217d2ab6f717fd7a12cd3c53a94efa6761b2cdfe81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061288b88",
        "unixDateTime": "1625097600",
        "functionSelector": "0x4ab0d190",
        "aggregatorAddress": "0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331",
        "__chainlink_result_collection__": [
          "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000205f"
        ]
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 86,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "resultcollect",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.171458+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.171458+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "0c8e18c2-c352-4af0-a282-a19fbcf03c2d",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "address": "0xb6EFEcE462EA6118A0A7EC1F2a3c7033b1F82967",
        "dataPrefix": "0xc23231a259fa1d606b3b1f8d31d6b169af467af60dbf0ac4e0014eb49553ccc70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f08086217d2ab6f717fd7a12cd3c53a94efa6761b2cdfe81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061288b88",
        "roundAnswer": "36893488147419111519",
        "unixDateTime": "1625097600",
        "functionSelector": "0x4ab0d190",
        "laterRoundAnswer": "36893488147419111520",
        "aggregatorAddress": "0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331",
        "earlierRoundAnswer": "36893488147419111518"
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 87,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "historical-price",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.172138+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.172138+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "48482e08-bed1-4956-8aa8-3ff6f2d9f38d",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "result": "36893488147419111518"
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 88,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "copy",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
        "copyPath": [
          "earlierRoundAnswer"
        ]
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.172638+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.172638+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "825ed16c-b662-4fb2-ac2d-abeee3259cfc",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "result": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000205e"
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 89,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "ethuint256",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.173151+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.173151+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "58ade305-bc91-4542-83b5-8b4e0018eebf",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "result": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000205e",
        "address": "0xb6EFEcE462EA6118A0A7EC1F2a3c7033b1F82967",
        "dataPrefix": "0xc23231a259fa1d606b3b1f8d31d6b169af467af60dbf0ac4e0014eb49553ccc70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f08086217d2ab6f717fd7a12cd3c53a94efa6761b2cdfe81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061288b88",
        "unixDateTime": "1625097600",
        "functionSelector": "0x4ab0d190",
        "aggregatorAddress": "0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331",
        "__chainlink_result_collection__": [
          "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000205e"
        ]
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 90,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "resultcollect",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.173677+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.173677+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "d7982f84-03be-4f41-a6ad-ee487c84fc6b",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "address": "0xb6EFEcE462EA6118A0A7EC1F2a3c7033b1F82967",
        "dataPrefix": "0xc23231a259fa1d606b3b1f8d31d6b169af467af60dbf0ac4e0014eb49553ccc70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f08086217d2ab6f717fd7a12cd3c53a94efa6761b2cdfe81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061288b88",
        "roundAnswer": "36893488147419111519",
        "unixDateTime": "1625097600",
        "functionSelector": "0x4ab0d190",
        "laterRoundAnswer": "36893488147419111520",
        "aggregatorAddress": "0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331",
        "earlierRoundAnswer": "36893488147419111518"
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 91,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "historical-price",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.174159+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.174159+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "cf3a1caa-723e-4b2f-ae50-6096007dd02e",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "result": "36893488147419111520"
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 92,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "copy",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
        "copyPath": [
          "laterRoundAnswer"
        ]
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.174617+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.174617+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "53d76d5c-01b2-4e0d-8515-9f1a4901635b",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "result": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000002060"
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 93,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "ethuint256",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.175071+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.175071+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "1fb908bb-9539-4617-9395-4e5796e214c2",
    "result": {
      "data": {
        "result": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000002060",
        "address": "0xb6EFEcE462EA6118A0A7EC1F2a3c7033b1F82967",
        "dataPrefix": "0xc23231a259fa1d606b3b1f8d31d6b169af467af60dbf0ac4e0014eb49553ccc70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f08086217d2ab6f717fd7a12cd3c53a94efa6761b2cdfe81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061288b88",
        "unixDateTime": "1625097600",
        "functionSelector": "0x4ab0d190",
        "aggregatorAddress": "0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331",
        "__chainlink_result_collection__": [
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000002060"
        ]
      },
      "error": null
    },
    "status": "completed",
    "task": {
      "ID": 94,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "resultcollect",
      "confirmations": null,
      "params": {
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.175515+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.175515+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "8763850e-80a6-4a1b-af04-aabfb69ff2c9",
    "result": {
      "data": {
      },
      "error": "insertEthTx failed while constructing EthTx data: number of collectors 2 != number of types in ABI encoding 4"
    },
    "status": "errored",
    "task": {
      "ID": 95,
      "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
      "type": "ethtx",
      "confirmations": 1,
      "params": {
        "abiEncoding": [
          "bytes32",
          "uint80",
          "uint80",
          "uint80"
        ]
      },
      "CreatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.175982+09:30",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:00.175982+09:30",
      "DeletedAt": null
    },
    "minimumConfirmations": 3,
    "confirmations": 1
  }
],
"createdAt": "2021-08-27T16:16:52.308136+09:30",
"finishedAt": "2021-08-27T16:18:59.22246+09:30",
"updatedAt": "2021-08-27T16:18:59.259186+09:30",
"creationHeight": "26956178",
"observedHeight": "26956180",
"payment": "0",
"initiator": {
  "id": 7,
  "jobSpecId": "33211805-3343-434c-8d51-9e4c3a8c3fef",
  "type": "runlog",
  "params": {
    "address": "0xb6efece462ea6118a0a7ec1f2a3c7033b1f82967"
  }
},
"type": "Direct request job run"
```

}

This is my job definition:

```
{
"name": "multi-word2",
"initiators": [
  {
    "id": 7,
    "jobSpecId": "33211805-3343-434c-8d51-9e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "runlog",
    "params": {
      "address": "0xb6efece462ea6118a0a7ec1f2a3c7033b1f82967"
    }
  }
],
"tasks": [
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "historical-price"
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "copy",
    "params": {
      "copyPath": [
        "roundAnswer"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "ethuint256"
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "resultcollect"
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "historical-price"
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "copy",
    "params": {
      "copyPath": [
        "earlierRoundAnswer"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "ethuint256"
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "resultcollect"
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "historical-price"
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "copy",
    "params": {
      "copyPath": [
        "laterRoundAnswer"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "ethuint256"
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "resultcollect"
  },
  {
    "jobSpecId": "332118053343434c8d519e4c3a8c3fef",
    "type": "ethtx",
    "confirmations": 1,
    "params": {
      "abiEncoding": [
        "bytes32",
        "uint80",
        "uint80",
        "uint80"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

}

Comment: The clue here is `"error": "insertEthTx failed while constructing EthTx data: number of collectors 2 != number of types in ABI encoding 4"`. The job is only collecting 1 of 3 results (it says 2 of 4, but the requestId is sort of "auto-collected")

Comment: Could you post the api response?

Comment: API response: 
Result:  {
  jobRunID: 'c06c9049-9417-4206-8219-da4bb64cf0f1',
  data: {
    roundAnswer: '36893488147419111519',
    earlierRoundAnswer: '36893488147419111518',
    laterRoundAnswer: '36893488147419111520'
  },
  result: null,
  statusCode: 200
}

If you compare the json output from the working example and mine, all looks similar (obviously I'm not doing any x 100 or anything), except for the part where the responses are meant to be appended to the array

Comment: Hmm... what happens when you test this as a web job with fewer result collects? Do you see which resultcollect this is failing on? Have you looked into making a toml version of this job? (I know the docs on the toml version aren't out yet...)

Comment: I've figured out that the issue is that the '__chainlink_result_collection__' array is not passed through from the resultsCollect to the external adapter call, whereas it is from resultsCollect to a normal HTTP Get task. I verified this by creating a job that contains 3 requests (EA, HTTPGET, EA), and observed that at the resultsCollect for the HTTPGet, the array correctly had 2 values, however on the final request (EA), the array didn't get passed through to the EA task, and the end result was just the 1 return value from the final EA. Will make an issue for this on GitHub

Comment: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/issues/4938 Will update this SO question once this has been addressed

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that the '**chainlink_result_collection**' array is not passed through from the resultsCollect to the EA (external adapter) call, whereas it is from resultsCollect to a normal HTTP Get task. I verified this by creating a job that contains 3 requests (EA, HTTPGET, EA), and observed that at the resultsCollect for the HTTPGet, the array correctly had 2 values, however on the final request (EA), the array didn't get passed through to the EA task, and the end result was just the 1 return value from the final EA

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/issues/4938) on this at the Chainlink GitHub